# SqlDataAdapter.Fill Invalid object name SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am trying to load data from a sql database table into a datagridview.

I get the following:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll  Additional information: Invalid object name 'JournalItems'.

when calling this:

```
SqlDataAdapter.Fill(<dataset here>, <datatable name here>)
```

I know that JournalItems is a valid datatable in my database. I have also tried using "MyInitialCatalog.dbo.JournalItems" and "MyInitialCatalog.JournalItems" with no success.

Here is my code:

```
private void loadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyInitialCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=myPassword";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM JournalItems";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
        sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
        sDs = new DataSet();
        JournalItems = new DataTable();
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "JournalItems");
        sTable = sDs.Tables["JournalItems"];
        connection.Close();
        journalItemsDataGridView.DataSource = sDs.Tables["JournalItems"];
        journalItemsDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
        saveData.Enabled = false;
        journalItemsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }
```

PS: here is the tutorial I am trying to follow:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-database-operations.htm

Comment: You shold give the name JournalItems to your DataTable : JournalItems = new DataTable("JournalItems");

Comment: Have you checked if the connection state is open following the call to Open()? Also try with just sAdapter.Fill(sDs);

Comment: Hey, I did check the state of the connection, and it is open. Also it still gives me the exact same error when using just sAdapter.Fill(sDs);

Comment: @JonathanWillcock you don't need to open a connection when using a dataadapter; it will do it for you, and return it to the state it found it afterwards

Comment: @CaiusJard I just wanted to be sure the connection string was ok!

Comment: Does the SELECT statement work in a query window in Management Studio?

Comment: Connection string is fine, I was able to pull all the table names that are in the database and print them out in a message box. I assume a SELECT statement would also work then? not sure how to use the query window you are referring to.

Comment: As a caution, it's possible for a SQL to work in management studio, but not the client app, due to differences in things like default schema. Toss this db access code out; it's no good (and shame on the person who wrote the tutorial youre following; he's encouraging you to code like we did in the 80s) - there's a much easier way via getting Visual Studio to write all this for you - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PS here is the tutorial I am trying to follow: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-database-operations.htm

Here is the tutorial set you should be following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx

Start with "Creating a simple data application"

Why do I advocate these over other ones you'll find on the web? Not an exhaustive list of reasons:

- The creators of the programming language you're using, created them as a model of best practice for working with datasets
- They suitably abstract(hide) much of the detail surrounding database interaction unless you need to get that low down and dirty
- It will clean up your code no end
- They're secure, fast and highly featured; you're automatically steered away from massive security no-no's like SQL injection
- They're the step up from what you're doing now; you don't lay your windows forms out by hand writing statements for placing and setting the properties of every component: you use a visual designer that offers a rich and professional editing experience and generates quality code. This is no different

If you get on board with the way microsoft recommend you to do your data access, your code will look a bit more like this:

```
MyTypedDataSet ds = new MyTypedDataSet();
MyTypedTableAdapter ta = new MyTypedTableAdapter();
ta.Fill(ds, "my where clause parameter value");
myGridview.DataSource = ds.MyTypedTable;
```

Or, minimally:

```
myGridview.DataSource = new MyTypedTableAdapter().GetXXX();
```

No conenction strings, no button click handlers full of dodgy SQL; reusable, maintainable, easy to read code that doesn't take 100 lines to push the minutae of database connectivity around

Comment: Awesome! Within 13 lines of code I replaced 235 and my program does the same thing. As a younger developer with little experience I am amazed how seamless this is.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your Dataset have no table called `"JournalItems"`.</strike>

Instead of

```
JournalItems = new DataTable();
```

Create the table inside the dataset:

```
sDs.Tables.Add("JournalItems");
```

Well, it turns out my initial answer was wrong. If the dataset does not have a table with the specified name, the dataAdapter should create it.

You need to make sure you are connected to the correct database and the correct schema. try adding the database name and schema name in the query itself:

```
SELECT * FROM DataBaseName.SchemaName.JournalItems
```

The rest of my original answer is still correct - only now that I've visited the link to the tutorial you are using, I need to add that you should avoid using class level variables to hold instances that implement the `IDisposable` interface - because then you can't use the `using` statement and you might end up not disposing instances you should dispose.

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder` all implements the `IDisposable` interface, so you really should use them inside a `using` statement. btw, you don't need the `SqlCommandBuilder` for this code.
Your code should look more like this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=myDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyInitialCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=myPassword";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM JournalItems";
sDs = new DataSet();
sDs.Tables.Add("JournalItems");

using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using(var sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand))
        {
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "JournalItems");
        }
    }
}
journalItemsDataGridView.DataSource = sDs.Tables["JournalItems"];
journalItemsDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
saveData.Enabled = false;
journalItemsDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: To clarify: I am not trying to add a table to sDs called JournalItems. The sql Database has a table called JournalItems, which I am trying to fill the dataset sDs with. This still gives me the same error as before.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Zohar Peled. I did try to specify the table using "DataBaseName.SchemaName.JournalItems" as I mentioned in my original question as follows: "MyInitialCatalog.dbo.JournalItems". My SchemaName may be wrong as I just assumed its dbo.