# Sql Database System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'dbo.LoginTbl'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I run my `c#` code, I'm getting an error at sda.Fill(dtbl).
I followed an online tutorial, and it seems that I'm not the only one with this problem.

I am NOT very experienced with `c#`!

I got the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'dbo.LoginTbl'.'

My code:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SPLAYZDK-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
   string query = "Select * from dbo.LoginTbl Where username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
   DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
   sda.Fill(dtbl);
   if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
   {
      this.Hide();
      MessageBox.Show("Login Auth accepted. Logging in...");
      Mainmenu main = new Mainmenu();
      main.Show();
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("User or pass is wrong!");
   }
}
```

I got an Sql Database named `SPLAYZDK-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS01` with a system database named `CrystalDB` with a table named `dbo.LoginTbl`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, the object you are referencing does not exist in the database you are connecting to. If you *are* showing us your code, ensure you paste it into your question, don't link to an off site resource.

Comment: Also, that statement is *wide* open to injection. You **need** to parametrise it. In fact, the whole thing is full of security issues, as you're clearly storing plain text passwords as well. You should **never** do this. If this *is* an online tutorial, I suggest finding a better one, that does not include such frowned upon, and security fatal practices.

Comment: For storing usernames and passwords, you want to research hashing and salting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SqlDataAdapter.Fill Invalid object name SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283781/sqldataadapter-fill-invalid-object-name-sql)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're connecting to the database but when it tries to find the table, it can't find the table in the default database.  This is because you're not specifying the CrystalDB database as the database that dbo.LoginTbl is in.

I would look into the "Initial Catalog" field on the connection string which you can view here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

You should just have to update your connection string to include the following:

```
Initial Catalog=CrystalDB;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you dont know how much time i spent on rewroting this. You're lifesaver <3

Comment: Nevermind, when i run the program on another machine, error 26 just pops up:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

Comment: The "Data Source=SPLAYZDK-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS01" part of your connection string specifies which machine the database is on as well as the database instance name.  If you're running it from a different machine, chances are it doesn't understand what "SPLAYZDK-LAPTOP" is.  Trying to hit a database on one machine from another one requires a valid network path.  If you have a static IP address, you can put the IP address in the connection string instead or possibly put a hosts file entry in to get it working.  Most machines don't by default though so you'll need to look into properly hosting it

Answer (score 0):

When i run the program on another machine, error 26 just pops up: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

The weird things is that it perfectly works on my PC. I am using a normal SQL server, not a local one.